# How to design a restful API with right semantic?

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, soap, restful-architecture

For instance, when selling a subscription to a user - what the system will do is

- create an organisation
- create a user
- create a subscription
- create an authentication
- create send out an email
- more operations based on business logic

And ALL above need to happen in SAME DB transaction as unit of work.

In SOAP semantic, it can be abstracted as `register(organisation, User, Plan, authentication details..more parameters)` and returns a `subscription` object.

But in Restful World, we will only deal with resources (only noun in URL) with HTTP verbs, and I found it is very hard to describe such business related logic instead of simple CRUD?

Comment: Where do you want all that stuff to happen? Inside the DB or in your business logic? If you had something like a stored procedure, you could post a ``registration_request`` item and the stored procedure/trigger could then do all the nitty gritty details such as create a new user etc. on DB side. Or you would have some business logic which looks for ``registration_request`` entries and then processes them (in the background). Basically, if your API is restful, it does not mean that the logic behind the API is not working on multiple "resources". Or you could re-compose your data.

Comment: From what I understand about SOAP vs RESTful services, I believe the only difference is SOAP has a defined structure defined by their library file (I forget the file's extension). So basically, the RESTful API could be described in the same semantic as the SOAP API.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for RESTFUL interfaces that they are mapped 1:1 to a database behind the API.

The logic in your case could be:

```
client -- POST: SubscriptionRequests(request) --> Server
client <-- RESPONSE: Status|Error   --  Server
```

Upon success, the Status response could contain properties which contain URI's to resulting new entries. Such as: `SubscriptionURI = "Subscriptions/ID49343" UserURI="Users/User4711"`.

And then someone could later on ask about active subscriptions with:

```
client -- GET: Subscriptions               --> Server
client <-- RESPONSE: Subscriptions | Error --  Server
```

This scheme could be considered RESTful. There is no problem with the fact, that the server has to manipulate a database (invisible to the client) and how it does that.

There is also not a problem that subsequent GET operations on the Subscriptions resource (and Users resource, for that matter) yield different output compared to before the SubscriptionRequest operation having been executed.

There is also no compelling reason to create a more chatty interface, just because you happen to have a certain data base modeling behind.
In that sense, it would be **worse** if you created an API like:

```
client -- POST: Users(newUser)    --> Server
client <-- RESPONSE: Status|Error -- Server
(if adding user worked bla bla ... )
client -- POST: Subscriptions(userId,other data..) --> Server
client <-- RESPONSE: Status|Error  -- Server
```

Which would basically just mean you did not design your API but simply copied the structure of your data base tables behind (and those will change next week).

In summary, it is not the business of API design to care about how the implementation handles the data base. If you need transactions or if you use some other ways to make sure all those things which need to be done are done is up to the implementation of that `SubscriptionRequests.POST` handler.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you think using the RPC mode ;-)

With REST, you must think using resources and representations. What you want to do is adding a subscription, so I would suggest to have a list resource for subscription with a method `POST` that implements the registration. In the request payload, you will provide what you need for the subscription and get back hints regarding the created subscription.

Here is a sample of the request:

```
POST /subscriptions/
{
    "organization": {
        "id": "organizationId",
        "name": "organization name",
        (...)
    },
    "user": {
        "lastName": "",
        (...)
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of the response:

```
{
    "id": "subscriptionId",
    "credentials": {
        (...)
    },
    (...)
}
```

You can notice that the payloads are proposals and perhaps don't exactly match to your subscription, user, ... structures. So feel free to adapt them.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry